# Using core.Token to pass a String Parameter as a number

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I raised a feature request on the CDK github account recently and was pointed in the direction of Core.Token as being pretty much the exact functionality I was looking for. I'm now having some issues implementing it and getting similar errors, heres the feature request I raised previously: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3800

So my current code looks something like this:

```
       fargate_service = ecs_patterns.LoadBalancedFargateService( 
          self, "Fargate", 
          cluster = cluster, 
          memory_limit_mib = core.Token.as_number(ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup(self, parameter_name='template-service-memory_limit')), 
          execution_role=fargate_iam_role, 
          container_port=core.Token.as_number(ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup(self, parameter_name='port')), 
          cpu = core.Token.as_number(ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup(self, parameter_name='template-service-container_cpu')), 
          image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_registry(ecrRepo) 
       )
```

When I try synthesise this code I get the following error:

```
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError:
  Error: Resolution error: Supplied properties not correct for "CfnSecurityGroupEgressProps"
    fromPort: "dummy-value-for-template-service-container_port" should be a number
    toPort: "dummy-value-for-template-service-container_port" should be a number.
  Object creation stack:
```

To me it seems to be getting past the validation requiring a number to be passed into the FargateService validation, but when it tried to create the resources after that ("CfnSecurityGroupEgressProps") it cant resolve the dummy string as a number. I'd appreciate any help on solving this or alternative suggestions to passing in values from AWS system params instead (I thought it might be possible to parse the values into here via a file pulled from S3 during the build pipeline or something along those lines, but that seems hacky).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help I think we've cracked this!

The problem was that I was passing "ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup" the solution is to provide the token with "ssm.StringParameter.value_for_string_parameter", when this is synthesised it stores the token and then upon deployment the value stored in system parameter store is substituted.

(We also came up with another approach for achieving similar which we're probably going to use over SSM approach, I've detailed below the code snippet if you're interested)

See the complete code below:

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_ec2 as ec2,
    aws_ssm as ssm,
    aws_iam as iam,
    aws_ecs as ecs,
    aws_ecs_patterns as ecs_patterns,
    core,
)
class GenericFargateService(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)


        containerPort = core.Token.as_number(ssm.StringParameter.value_for_string_parameter(
            self, 'template-service-container_port'))

        vpc = ec2.Vpc( 
            self, "cdk-test-vpc", 
            max_azs=2 
        )

        cluster = ecs.Cluster( 
            self, 'cluster', 
            vpc=vpc 
        )

        fargate_iam_role = iam.Role(self,"execution_role", 
            assumed_by = iam.ServicePrincipal("ecs-tasks"), 
            managed_policies=[iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess")] 
        ) 

        fargate_service = ecs_patterns.LoadBalancedFargateService( 
            self, "Fargate", 
            cluster = cluster, 
            memory_limit_mib = 1024, 
            execution_role=fargate_iam_role, 
            container_port=containerPort, 
            cpu = 512,
            image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_registry("000000000000.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/template-service-ecr") 
        ) 

        fargate_service.target_group.configure_health_check(path=self.node.try_get_context("health_check_path"), port="9000")    

app = core.App()
GenericFargateService(app, "generic-fargate-service", env={'account':'000000000000', 'region': 'eu-west-1'})
app.synth()
```

Solutions to problems are like buses, apparently you spend ages waiting for one and then two arrive together. And I think this new bus is the option we're probably going to run with.

The plan is to have developers provide an override for the cdk.json file withing their code repos, which can then put parsed into the CDK pipeline where the generic code will be synthesised. This file will contain some "context", the context will then be used within the CDK to set our variables for the LoadBalancedFargate service.

I've included some code snippets for setting cdk.json file and then using its values within code below.

Example CDK.json:

```
{
    "app": "python3 app.py",
    "context": {
        "container_name":"template-service",
        "memory_limit":1024,
        "container_cpu":512,
        "health_check_path": "/gb/template/v1/status",
        "ecr_repo": "000000000000.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/template-service-ecr"
    }
}
```

Python example for assigning context to variables:

```
memoryLimitMib = self.node.try_get_context("memory_limit")
```

I believe we could also use a Try/Catch block to assign some default values to this if not provided by the developer in their CDK.json file.

I hope this post has provided some useful information to those looking for ways to create a generic template for deploying CDK code! I don't know if we're doing the right thing here, but this tool is so new it feels like some common patterns dont exist yet.